# Keep the list menu on one line and prevent new line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep this menu on one line, when the browser gets resized, some of them make a new line and go under the first line.
Here is my code:

```css
.menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
 

}
.item{
  float: left;
}
.item a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 100px 16px 100px;
  text-decoration: none; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  
}
.item a:hover{
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
 
 <header>
 <ul class="menu">
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Popular Categories</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Today's Special</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `display: flex`. I recommend you to have a read here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.menu{
  display: flex; 
  list-style: none;
}
.item a{
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #000;
}
.item a:hover{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 
 <header>
 <ul class="menu">
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Popular Categories</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Today's Special</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        </ul>
</header>
```